# How do I localize strings in a custom control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a custom wizard control that I am modifying with a Title and a SubTitle.  How do I save and localize strings in the control?  Here is the SubTitle property:

```
[Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue("Description for the new page."), Description("The subtitle of the page."), Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string Subtitle
{
    get { return subtitle; }
    set
    {
        if (subtitle != value)
        {
            Region regionToInvalidate = GetTextRegionToInvalidate();
            subtitle = value;
            regionToInvalidate.Union(GetTextRegionToInvalidate());

            Invalidate(regionToInvalidate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't that done when you add the resources localized file?

Comment: It is not automatic for the string properties that I have.  Controls that are dropped on to the wizard page are automatically localized though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the Localizable attribute

```
[Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue("Description for the new page."), Description("The subtitle of the page."), Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[Localizable(true)]
public string Subtitle
{
    get { return subtitle; }
    set
    {
        if (subtitle != value)
        {
            Region regionToInvalidate = GetTextRegionToInvalidate();
            subtitle = value;
            regionToInvalidate.Union(GetTextRegionToInvalidate());

            Invalidate(regionToInvalidate);
        }
    }
}
```